# Batch conditional delete from dynamodb without sort key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-dynamodb

I am shifting my database from mongodb to dynamo db. I have a problem with delete function from a table where labName is partition key and serialNumber is my sort key and there is one Id as feedId I want to delete all the records from the table where labName is given and feedId is NOT IN (array of ids).
I am doing it in mongo like below mentioned code

Is there a way with BatchWriteItem where i can add condition for feedId without sort key.

```
let dbHandle = await getMongoDbHandle(dbName);
    let query = {
        feedid: {$nin: feedObjectIds}
    }
let output = await dbModule.removePromisify(dbHandle, 
dbModule.collectionNames.feeds, query);
```

Comment: DynamoDB does not support that. For batch deletes you must list the complete primary key of every item you are deleting.

Comment: @MatthewPope Thanks. Finally i had to make a request first to get the sort key and then I did BatchWrite DeleteRequest.

Answer (score 0):

While working with DynamoDB, you can perform Conditional Retrieval (GET) / Deletion (DELETE) on the records only & only if you have provided all of the attributes for the Primary Key. For example:

- For a **Simple Primary key,** you only need to provide a value for the Partition key.
- For a **Composite Primary Key**, you must need to provide values for both the Partition key & sort key.